# How to get my Linux Wi-Fi to reliably roam from AP to AP

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, networkmanager, wireless-roaming

I'm trying to get my Linux to reliably roam from AP to AP. Right now I'm using iwlwifi - iwd - NetworkManager combo to manage everything and apart from roaming everything works reasonably well and I'm happy with it.

But I'm unable to get **reliable** roaming experience.

My laptop clings to the AP that is far away (*< -80dBm with 40MHz channel*) and completely ignores AP that is literally next to it (*-60dBm, 160MHz channel*). That connection to a "weak AP" has a lot of transmission errors, traffic stops for few seconds at a time etc - the experience is horrible, wifi basically does not work.

I also have to mention that we are talking about 5/6GHz wifi network as I know that 2.4GHz networks have this problem in much larger scale due to the fact that 2.4GHz will reach much further than higher bands.

### (Not the) Sticky client problem

This problem happens at multiple locations with different network vendors (Ubiquiti vs Aruba) so my best guess would be that the wifi network is not the problem. As @Peregrino69 mentioned (Thank you!), the correct name for this is **Sticky client problem** and common solution is to try to force the client to roam - usualy by setting some RSSI threshold, which would make the AP to send DEAUTH packet to the client, thus forcing the client to reassociate/roam.

But Sticky client problem means that client is unwilling to switch to another AP. From logs of IWD I can clearly see that it is trying to but failing. Meaning I don't have this problem.

### Debugging IWD?

I downloaded sources & added many debugs so I can figure out what and where is happening. I know that IWD is the responsible piece of SW that handles roaming and I know it tries to roam but fails.

```
01| station_roam_scan_notify() Will do scan & prepare for roaming  [BSS=AP-FAR-AWAY  SSID='xxx'
02| station_roam_scan_notify()  |- Candidate [BSS=AP-CLOSE  SSID='xxx' FREQ=5180  RANK=589  DBM=-7500  DATARATE=72.0]
03| station_roam_scan_notify()  |     |- This IS a roaming candidate!
04| station_roam_scan_notify()  |- Candidate [BSS=AP-FAR-AWAY  SSID='xxx' FREQ=5180  RANK=140  DBM=-8100  DATARATE=17.2]
05| station_roam_scan_notify()  |     |- SKIPPING: Already connected
06| station_roam_scan_notify() Calling station_transition_start()
07| station_transition_start() Starting roaming process - will try BSS one by one
08| station_transition_start() AP-CLOSE|  Trying to roam
09| station_try_next_transition() Trying to roam    [IF=36  TGT=AP-CLOSE]
10| station_fast_transition() ft_authenticate() branch taken
11| wiphy_radio_work_insert() Inserting work item 6
12| station_fast_transition() wiphy_radio_work_insert() -> FT / PRIO_CONNECT
13| wiphy_radio_work_insert() Inserting work item 7
14| station_try_next_transition() Trying Fast Transition  [SUCCESS]
15| station_transition_start() AP-CLOSE|  Successfully started roaming!
16| station_transition_start() Roaming process SUCCESFULLY started!
17| wiphy_radio_work_next() Starting work item 6
18| netdev_mlme_notify() MLME notification Frame TX Status(60)
19| netdev_unicast_notify() Unicast notification Frame(59)
20| netdev_mlme_notify() MLME notification Remain on Channel(55)
21| netdev_mlme_notify() MLME notification Cancel Remain on Channel(56)
22| wiphy_radio_work_done() Work item 6 done
23| wiphy_radio_work_next() Starting work item 0
24| ft_associate() We got new BS but did not auth YET!!
25| station_ft_work_ready() ft_associate(AP-CLOSE) returned -2
26| station_ft_work_ready() Calling station_transition_start() as -ENOENT
27| station_transition_start() Starting roaming process - will try BSS one by one
28| station_transition_start() Roaming process FAILED for all candidate BSS
29| station_roam_failed() 36
30| station_roam_failed() [SIGNAL_LOW=1  AP_DIRECTED=0]
```

### 802.11r be damned

From this log I assume the following:

1. IWL would like to roam as expected (from AP-FAR-AWAY to AP-CLOSE, which makes complete sense)
2. We are trying to roam using 802.11r (FT)
3. We are not yet authed to the AP-CLOSE as we did not receive the necessary information from driver (yet)
4. Cannot associate to the new AP -> FT roaming fails

I did some more testing: I disabled 802.11r (FT) and lo and behold, now the computer *can* indeed roam as I would expect it to roam. Yes, there is an (short) outage when roaming as we have to do full authentication to the new AP, but it works.

### Nothing is ever easy

I have reached Denis Kenzior (one of the authors of IWD) on IRC and he told me that FT should indeed work just fine. After some digging we (well, Denis) have found that the main culprit is *timing*.

**Technical details:** Without going into *too much* technial details, the issue seems to be race condition in (probably) Intel AX210 firmware and Ubiquiti. Ubiquiti sends FT association frame, but for some unknown reason it sends it way later than IWD/Intel AX210 firmware waits for. The log above paints (almost) a full picture and that's why I'm keeping it there - the IWD waits for FT association frame between `MLME notification Remain on Channel(55)` (line 20) and `MLME notification Cancel Remain on Channel(56)` (line 21). And that frame contains necessary information for `ft_associate` (line 26) to work properly. That frame is received after this log snippet ends, which is of course too late

We are getting quite deep inside kernel/iwlwifi etc. Hopefully we can get either some workaround this issue or we can fix it.

I will keep this post as kind of a notepad for me and for anyone that might have similar problem.

For now it seems that this issue may happen if you have AX210 card and slow-ish AP (as my Ubiquiti at home).

Comment: This is known as "Sticky Client Problem". Does this happen everywhere, or in a specific location? Asking cuz your adapter seems to be doing exactly what it should - to ensure connectivity it's _supposed_ to hold on to the connection it has. A client should roam _only_ when it loses connection. Connection loss happens when infrastructure determines the signal quality is below set threshold and kicks the client out. The infra has multiple tools (band steering, client steering...) which are developed to improve roaming, but if they aren't in use and thresholds aren't correctly set...

Comment: So as to your 2nd question - the component responsible for roaming is the AP.

Comment: Multiple locations - at work, at home.
I'd argue that it should migrate, because it loses connection (well, drops packets) in a way that ICMP ping will have ~50% failure rate. 
But the thing is that even if I set the threshold to e.g. -80dBm and the AP kicks the client out, the client will try to reconnect to the *same* AP. Even though that same AP did kick that client 
Also I don't really think that it is the AP. I think the client is solely responsible for choosing AP and therefore the client is ultimetely responsible. Even though there are some newer techniques that should help this

Comment: ... like 802.11r and 802.11v, but these only help this fundamental issue that there is no real "central brain" of the wifi network as is in GSM network, where clients are more like mindless "drones" that do whatever the network tells them to do. But I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: Think abt a large office. There are many locations where multiple APs are bcasting the same SSID with similar strength. Wi-Fi signal's _never_ steady and it's very prone to interference, so on client's point of view the AP with strongest signal keeps changing. What'd happen to the connectivity if the client always roamed when it detected a stronger signal? Every new association drops the connection. If you _can_ set some threshold on the NIC, do; but try something like -75 - -60. -80 is already _very_ poor signal.

Comment: Even the association with the weaker signal is expected. When the client loses connection, it's supposed to try to reassociate with the original signal first. Can't remember if it's the number of failing attempts or a certain time period when it tries a different radio.

Comment: In an office and in a scenario that has multiple APs with +- same level and/or fluctuating signal quality I would understand that the connection is less then ideal. But I'm talking about scenario where I'm in 1 location near AP1. Then after few hours I will go to another location where AP1 can barely reach, but there is an AP2 directly above me. And even though I'm stable next to the AP2, my client will insist on trying to get to the AP1 

-80dBm is really poor signal, I know - and the other AP has -60dBm or better. And the client still tries to hold on to the objectively worse one.